# WordPress plugin Contact Form 7 showing error on all required fields on file upload

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I am seeking for solution to the problem on file upload field. When I am doing Browse and select a file it shows errors on all required fields. However this ideally should display on clicking of Submit button. Can someone please help on this? My Cf7 code is mentioned below -

```
<label> Your name
    [text* your-name autocomplete:name] </label>

<label> Your email
    [email* your-email autocomplete:email] </label>

<label> Subject
    [text* your-subject] </label>

<label> File Upload
[file* testfilename id:testid class:testclass] </label>

<label> Your message (optional)
    [textarea your-message] </label>

[submit "Submit"]
```

Error Image -

[Error on file upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1iEO.jpg)

Tested by creating different forms and checked all JS problems in browser console.